# ESP32 server does not see client

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am trying to connect two ESP32 modules via Wi-Fi and send info. However, I am stuck at the server side. The client shows that it has connected to Wi-Fi, but server side does not print "New Client",hence it does not see the client. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, perhaps someone has tried this before.

Server side:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "ESP32";
const char* password = "123";

 WiFiServer server(80);    

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);


Serial.println("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);  



IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
Serial.println(IP);
Serial.print("MAC address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
server.begin();
}

void loop(){

WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

if (client) 
{ Serial.println("New Client.");          

while (client.connected()) 
{           
Serial.println(client.connected());
Serial.println("Client connected.");
Serial.println("");

}
client.stop();
Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
Serial.println("");
}
}
```

Client side:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
 #include <SPI.h>
const char* ssid = "ESP32";
const char* password =  "123";



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
    scanNetworks();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

   Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

    }

void loop() {

}
void scanNetworks() {
  // scan for nearby networks:
  Serial.println("** Scan Networks **");
  byte numSsid = WiFi.scanNetworks();

  // print the list of networks seen:
  Serial.print("SSID List:");
  Serial.println(numSsid);
  // print the network number and name for each network found:
  for (int thisNet = 0; thisNet<numSsid; thisNet++) {
    Serial.print(thisNet);
    Serial.print(") Network: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID(thisNet));
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try sending some data from the client to the server?

Comment: @TarickWelling I did not! I shall try once I get home. If I use client.write();, do I need some kind of listener on the other side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data from your client to your server. `WiFiServerAvailable::available` will return something when:

> Gets a client that is connected to the server and has data available
>   for reading.

And:

> Returns a Client object; if no Client has data available for reading,
>   this object will evaluate to false in an if-statement

As per [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiServerAvailable).

No reading has to be done on the server side but that will result in a infinite loop because `WifiClient::connected` will return `true` until the data is read and the connection is closed. As per [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClientConnected).

Answer (score 0):

with normal web server of Arduino core there is this line in [WebServer.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h)

```
virtual WiFiClient client() { return _currentClient; }
```

So in order to see if a client is connect you can write

```
void checkClient(){

  WiFiClient myclient = server.client();

  if(myclient==0){
    Serial.println("client not connected");
  }
  if(myclient.available()){
    Serial.println("client available");
  }  
  if(myclient.connected()){
    Serial.println("client connected");
  }
}
```

Run this funciton in the Arduino loop and it will return the different statuses.